# Why are all qrcode images sent to the user, one user should get a qrcode image

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a PHP script which will be used to send emails to all email data from the database. When I send emails to all users, I generate a QR Code to send to each user.

But the problem is that each user accepts all existing QR Code. Each user should receive one QR Code image.

Here is the script:

```
if($email_list == "semua"){
    $query_email_list = mysqli_query($koneksi, "SELECT email FROM pengunjung");

    while($data_email = mysqli_fetch_array($query_email_list)){
        QRCode::png($data_email['email'], $tempdir. $data_email['email'].".png", $quality, $ukuran, $padding);
        $mail_body .= "<br><br><img src='http://besp.ga/prudential/admin/qr_code_generator/temp/".$data_email['email'].".png'>";
        $sent = mail($data_email['email'], $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_headers);
    }
}else{
    QRCode::png($data_email['email'], $tempdir. $email_list.".png", $quality, $ukuran, $padding);
    $mail_body .= "<br><br><img src='http://besp.ga/prudential/admin/qr_code_generator/temp/".$email_list.".png'>";
    $sent = mail($email_list, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_headers);
}
```

Comment: hi, i believe you might want to remove that domain from your code. regarding 'why it sent to every user', you ran a query that takes every user... that `SELECT email FROM pengunjung`.

Comment: i want to sent like email blast

Comment: What does 'each user accepts all existing QR Code'  mean? What URLs are you getting in the email sent to each user?

Comment: @danblack it means one user get 10 QR Code (10 is from DB), the truth is one user get one QR Code

Comment: Ah, 'accepts' as meaning 'gets'. It wasn't obvious. (to me anyway) When in doubt about meaning of works a concrete example of output can help. The answer below is obviously right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating on users and on every iteration you are appending a new bit with the qrcode to the mail body. So the first user has mail body with one qrcode, second user -- with two, third -- with three etc.

You need to change your loop to something like this:

```
    while($data_email = ...){
        QRCode::png($data_email['email'], $tempdir. $data_email['email'].".png", $quality, $ukuran, $padding);
        $qrcode_body = "<br><br><img src='http://server/path/to/".$data_email['email'].".png'>";
        $sent = mail($data_email['email'], $mail_subject, $mail_body . $qrcode_body, $mail_headers);
    }
```